# Recyclerview takes more width than parent width

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I don't know why the `RecyclerView` takes more width than the parent width even if I set the width in the xml to match_parent. I don't think there is anything wrong with the xml but I am not sure with the Adapter. Here is the Adapter's code:

```
class ListAdapter(val data : ArrayList<devices>): RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
            return ViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.devicelist, parent, false)
            )
        }

        override fun getItemCount() = data.size

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val list = data[position]
            holder.view.listimgtxt.text = list.name
            holder.view.listsw1.text = list.sw1
            holder.view.listsw2.text = list.sw2
            holder.view.listsw3.text = list.sw3
            holder.view.listsw4.text = list.sw4
        }
        class ViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
    }
```

Here is my xml code(removed imageviews and textviews since code is too long):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The xml that contains the recyclerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

The output:[image]

Comment: share devicelist.xml code

Comment: Paste your devicelist.xml and recyclerveiw  xml

Comment: post everything please

Comment: @Ogbe devicelist.xml is the layout I don't have recyclerview.xml

Comment: add the layout that contains the recycler view... the layout you posted only contains the parent layout, cant do much with that.

Comment: @Ogbe Oh ok! I completely forgot. Sorry I didn't know you were referring to that

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a constraint layout and set the width of the Recycler view to 0dp and constraint its to the left and right of the parent... Match parent does not respect constraints.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also, set the width of all the images in the list item to 0dp so that they adjust to screen size according to the constraint set.

Comment: It still shows the same thing. I changed the xml to exactly like yours but then it still outputs the same thing.

Comment: also do you wish for extra items to be overflown to the next line? then you should use a grid layout manager

Comment: No. I don't think I would want that I only want items to be below it. Thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: yea, I just saw that those are not list items but they are part of the layout